# How change Powered By Liferay

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

How can i change powered by liferay to custom label and hyperlink when clicking liferay .  I am new to liferay development . Can some suggest to create hook for changing basic functionalities in liferay 7.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a fragment in Liferay 7

Here is the tutorial
https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/overriding-a-modules-jsps

The latest IDE Of Liferay (Released in Dec 2016) provides option to create Liferay fragment hook through IDE.
Previous IDE didnt had the support, other option is you can create through Blade.

Answer (score 0):

To change powered by liferay you must create your custom theme for the liferay.

In liferay you can customize the liferay default theme and there you can modify powered by and liferay with any message as per your requirement.

For  more info use these links: [Creating theme](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/creating-a-theme-project-in-the-plugins-sdk) and [Creating basic theme](http://proliferay.com/basic-liferay-theme-development/).